# Solomon Islands - Diving or snorkeling operators in Munda

Tags: diving, solomon-islands, munda

I want to snorkel some wrecks sitting in shallow water off Munda. Dive Munda used to run such trips, but they are closed for now.

Are there other diving or snorkeling operators in Munda?